# Leaflet map not recognizing layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've created a few GeoJSON layers in Leaflet, but I'm trying to remove certain layers when a button is hit. Leaflet isn't recognizing my layers for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
var GE_Countries = L.geoJson(GE_Countries)
var GE_Cities = L.geoJson(GE_Cities)
var map = L.map('map', {
    // set geographic center
    center: [41.4, -110],
    // set initial zoom level
    zoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 8,
    minZoom: 2
});
var attribute;
var attributes;

if (map.hasLayer(map)) {
    console.log("map layer present");
} else {
    console.log("no layer present")
}
```

The console logs "no layer present".

Answer (score 1):

```
GE_Cities.addTo(map);
GE_Countries.addTo(map);

if (map.hasLayer(GE_Cities)) {
    …
}
```

Comment: And you check if the map has a layer `map` where I suppose you want to check if the map has a layer `GE_Countries` or something like that.